# Jasmine test error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing a test in angular 8 to check if the component method has been called. In my case I am checking if method
removeSettlementConfirmation is called. I am not sure if callThrough or returning empty obserable is the best way of testing 
if the method is called

If I write

```
spyOn(component, 'removeSettlementConfirmation').and.callThrough();
```

I get error   TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

But if  I write

```
spyOn(component, 'removeSettlementConfirmation').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });
```

The error is gone.

What is right way of testing this method is called ?

Unit test

```
fit('removeSettlementConfirmation should be called', () => {
        let clientCompanyOpiId = 10;
        let title = `Delete Settlement Account`;
        let message = `Are you sure you want to delete this OPI account?`;
        let testConfirmModal = ({
            title: 'Delete Settlement Account',
            message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this OPI account?'
        } as ConfirmModalComponent);
        component.confirmModal = testConfirmModal;
        spyOn(component, 'removeSettlementConfirmation').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });
        spyOn(clientService, 'getNumberOfTradesWhereOPIIsSetOn').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} });
        component.removeSettlementConfirmation(clientCompanyOpiId);
        expect(component.removeSettlementConfirmation).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Component code

```
removeSettlementConfirmation(clientCompanyOpiId: number): void {
        this.clientService.getNumberOfTradesWhereOPIIsSetOn(clientCompanyOpiId)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    const assignedTrades = data;
                    const trades = +assignedTrades > 1 ? 's' : '';
                    const message = assignedTrades
                        ? `This OPI account is set on ${assignedTrades} trade${trades}. Are you sure you want to delete it?`
                        : `Are you sure you want to delete this OPI account?`;
                    const title = `Delete Settlement Account`;
                    this.confirmModal.openModal(title, message, clientCompanyOpiId);
                },
                error => {
                    this.alertService.showMessage("Error", "Unable to get Associated Trades for Settlement Account", MessageSeverity.error);
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
and.returnValue():
```

A spy can be made to return a preset/fixed value (without the need for calling the actual methods using `and.callThrough())`. This can be achieved by chaining the `spyOn()` function with `and.returnValue().`

```
    fit('removeSettlementConfirmation should be called', () => {
                let clientCompanyOpiId = 10;
                let title = `Delete Settlement Account`;
                let message = `Are you sure you want to delete this OPI account?`;
                let testConfirmModal = ({
                    title: 'Delete Settlement Account',
                    message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this OPI account?'
                } as ConfirmModalComponent);
                component.confirmModal = testConfirmModal;
                spyOn(component, 'removeSettlementConfirmation').and.returnValue("mock response"); // with returnValue() you should return the actual mockResponse
                spyOn(clientService, 'getNumberOfTradesWhereOPIIsSetOn').and.returnValue("test"); // with returnValue() you should return the actual mockResponse
                component.removeSettlementConfirmation(clientCompanyOpiId);
                expect(component.removeSettlementConfirmation).toHaveBeenCalled();

                // you can verify by calling the methods and expected response
                const response = component.removeSettlementConfirmation();
                expect(response).toEqaul("mock response");
            });
```

Comment: If using return value then actual underlying method is not tested right. Or since is just checking if method is called, its enough to use returnvalue ?

Comment: Also in my method i was using expect(component.removeSettlementConfirmation).toHaveBeenCalled(); But i dont see that in your case

Comment: Can you also tell me why my .and.callThrough(); is not working ?